# expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, identifier

I can't seem to squash this bug!

I am working on a small project, trying to add background audio to my app. I was doing pretty well until this error showed up.

Error on line 52 on .m file:

```
//
//  UDMenuScene.m
//  iLabyrinth
//
//  Created by Rolandas Razma on 5/12/10.
//  Copyright 2010 UD7. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UDMenuScene.h"
#import "UDPickMapScene.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "UDHelpScene.h"
#import "iLabyrinth.h"
#import "CCDirector.h"

@implementation UDMenuScene
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject

- (id)init 
{
    if( (self = [super init]) )
    {
         [self addChild:[UDMenuLayer node]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation UDMenuLayer
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject

- (id)init {

    if( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        [self setIsTouchEnabled: YES];
        CGSize _winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        //AVAudioPlayer *player;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"menu" ofType:@"mp3"]];
        NSError *error;
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        // Add background
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"menu%@.png", (isDeviceIPad()?@"~ipad":([iLabyrinth hightRes]?@"@2x":@""))]];
        [sprite setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
        [self addChild:sprite];
        _backgroundLayer = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[iLabyrinth textureName]];
        [[_backgroundLayer texture] setAliasTexParameters];
        [self addChild:_backgroundLayer];
        // Add "Pay" button
        CCSprite *playSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"play.png"];
            [playSprite setTag:MenuButtonPlay];
            [playSprite setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.0f)];
            [playSprite setPosition:CGPointMake(_winSize.width /2, _winSize.height /2)];
        [_backgroundLayer addChild:playSprite];

        // Add "Help" button        
        CCSprite *helpSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"help.png"];
            [helpSprite setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 1.0f)];
            [helpSprite setTag:MenuButtonHelp];
            [helpSprite setPosition:CGPointMake(_winSize.width /2, _winSize.height /2 -[helpSprite boundingBox].size.height /2)];
        [_backgroundLayer addChild:helpSprite];
    }

    return self;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CCStandardTouchDelegate


- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [_backgroundLayer convertTouchToNodeSpace:[touches anyObject]];

    for( CCSprite *sprite in [_backgroundLayer children] ){
        if( [sprite tag] <= 0 ) continue;

        if( CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchPoint) ){

            [sprite setColor:ccGREEN];
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"click.caf"];

            switch ( [sprite tag] ) {
                case MenuButtonPlay: {
                    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSplitRows transitionWithDuration:1.0f scene:[UDPickMapScene node]]];
                    break;
                }
                case MenuButtonHelp: {
                    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSplitRows transitionWithDuration:1.0f scene:[UDHelpScene node]]];
                    break;
                }
            }

            return;
        }

    }

}


@end
```

and here is my .h file:

```
//
//  UDMenuScene.h
//  iLabyrinth
//
//  Created by Rolandas Razma on 5/12/10.
//  Copyright 2010 UD7. All rights reserved.
//

#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

typedef enum {
    MenuButtonPlay =1,
    MenuButtonHelp,
    MenuButtonPlayHeaven,
} MenuButton;

@class player;

@interface UDMenuScene : CCScene {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@end

@interface UDMenuLayer : CCLayer {
    CCSpriteBatchNode   *_backgroundLayer;
}
@end
```

Comment: Which line is line 52?

Comment: Which is line 52? - it helps to provide a small test case that fails. Delete lines of code until you have just the issue and no extraneous code

Comment: `@class player;` should be `@class Player;`.  This is not your problem, you it doesn't help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring a class called `player`.

`@class player;`

(forward declaration saying `player` is a class type)

but you are also using `player` as an identifier

`@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;`

(property declaration saying `player` is an instance of `AVAudioPlayer`).

To prevent similar errors, never ever declare classes with names starting with lowercase letter (use `Player` instead) and also use a custom prefix to avoid name collisions (e.g. `MYPlayer`).

Comment: You're right that it's to do with the @class declaration in the header file, although I don't think the issue is to do with the property declaration; it looks like you can declare a property whose identifier is a class name. However, since `player` hasn't been declared in `-[UDMenuLayer init]` it's being interpreted as the forward-declared `player` class.

Comment: @AlexRozanski Yes, the problem is not with the declaration. However, once you try to use the property and assign to it, there is a problem.

Comment: From what I can see, he's not assigning to it from anywhere. If he's using property auto-synthesis, the generated ivar will be `_player`, not `player`.

Comment: @AlexRozanski That's true. Overlooked that. He's trying to assign into  the class :)

Comment: You guys are too smart :) I was declaring the class due to the fact that if I do not, I get the "Unknown type name 'player'". I've renamed it all to myPlayer for proper coding format and removed the class, but now I still have the original error and the new error I mentioned. Any ideas? Thanks a ton.

Comment: ALSO: I am using this guide to add it, just assume I renamed player to myPlayer. Frustrating, such a simple guide! http://alirazadeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/03/ios-tutorials.html

Comment: @user2964209 remove the @class and use `_player` or `self.player` instead of `player`.